# Convert MariaDB query with GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT col1 ORDER BY col2) to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, mariadb

I am moving an application from MariaDB to PostgreSQL.

I have a query that uses GROUP_CONCAT on DISTINCT values of col1 that are ordered by col2. This statement is not possible in PostgreSQL, so I have to find an alternative way to do this.

The working MariaDB query is this:

```
SELECT
    r.result_id,
    r.sample_id,
    sm.sample_id AS parameter_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(sm.metadata_value) ORDER BY smt.display_in_concat SEPARATOR ' ') AS parameter,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(sms.metadata_value) ORDER BY smts.display_in_concat SEPARATOR ' - ') AS sample_info
FROM
    results r
    JOIN samples_metadata sm ON r.parameter_id = sm.sample_id
    JOIN samples_metadata sms ON r.sample_id = sms.sample_id
    JOIN metadata_types smt ON sm.meta_type_id = smt.meta_type_id
    JOIN metadata_types smts ON sms.meta_type_id = smts.meta_type_id
WHERE
    smt.display_in_concat > 0
    AND smts.display_in_concat > 0
    AND r.instance_id = 1625152480
GROUP BY
    r.result_id,
    r.sample_id,
    sm.sample_id;
```

Output:

| result_id | sample_id | parameter_id | parameter | sample_info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 42 | 11 | param1 metric1 | Name - Code |
| 112 | 42 | 12 | param2 metric2 | Name - Code |

The PostgreSQL query I have now is as follows:

```
SELECT
    r.result_id,
    r.sample_id,
    sm.sample_id AS parameter_id,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT sm.metadata_value, ' ') AS parameter,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT sms.metadata_value, ' - ') AS sample_info
FROM
    results r
    JOIN samples_metadata sm ON r.parameter_id = sm.sample_id
    JOIN metadata_types smt ON sm.meta_type_id = smt.meta_type_id
    JOIN samples_metadata sms ON r.sample_id = sms.sample_id
    JOIN metadata_types smts ON sms.meta_type_id = smts.meta_type_id
WHERE
    smt.display_in_concat > 0
    AND smts.display_in_concat > 0
    AND r.instance_id = 1625152480
GROUP BY
    r.result_id,
    r.sample_id,
    sm.sample_id;
```

Output:

| result_id | sample_id | parameter_id | parameter | sample_info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 42 | 11 | metric1 param1 | Code - Name |
| 112 | 42 | 12 | metric2 param2 | Code - Name |

Note that the concatenated values in the parameter and sample_info columns have switched (`Code - Name` instead of `Name - Code`). This is because I cannot use `ORDER BY smt.display_in_concat` in the STRING_AGG function of PostgreSQL. If you add the ORDER BY part you get the following error:

```
Error: in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list
```

I have created examples on db-fiddle.com.

[MariaDB](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3CSyytyLp1YhUuQXk34rKb/3)
[PostgreSQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9KURVnarapXadCHv8EBZDM/3)

I need a query that duplicates the output as generated in the MariaDB example.

Thanks :)

Comment: @Zegarek made me aware what my mistake is. In the group_concat ordering uses similar functionality to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, even though ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get to the right result with PostgreSQL.

This is the query, it uses subqueries to order the parameter and sample_info fields in the case of the example.

```
SELECT
    r.result_id,
    r.sample_id,
    sm.sample_id AS parameter_id,
    (SELECT string_agg(metadata_value, ' ')
        FROM (SELECT metadata_value, submt.display_in_concat
              FROM samples_metadata ssm
              JOIN metadata_types submt ON ssm.meta_type_id = submt.meta_type_id
              WHERE sample_id = r.parameter_id AND submt.display_in_concat > 0
              ORDER BY submt.display_in_concat) AS subquery) AS parameter,
    (SELECT string_agg(metadata_value, ' - ')
        FROM (SELECT metadata_value, submt.display_in_concat
              FROM samples_metadata ssm
              JOIN metadata_types submt ON ssm.meta_type_id = submt.meta_type_id
              WHERE sample_id = r.sample_id AND submt.display_in_concat > 0
              ORDER BY submt.display_in_concat) AS subquery) AS sample_info
FROM
    results r
    JOIN samples_metadata sm ON r.parameter_id = sm.sample_id
WHERE
    r.instance_id = 1625152480
GROUP BY
    r.result_id,
    r.sample_id,
    sm.sample_id,
    r.parameter_id;
```

You can try yourself with this db-fiddle:
[Solution](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9KURVnarapXadCHv8EBZDM/8)